# Node js using Sequalize, Relations one to many

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have this database:

- author
- book

so one author can create many books, so I have the relationship one to many. I created the relations between both tables. and I just don't know what to do for get a list's books of one author, I'm working in the controller and I have this function:

```
import { Author } from '../models/author.js'
import { Book } from '../models/book.js';

    export async function getItems(req, res){ 
        try {
            const authors = await Author.findAll({
                include: Book
            })
            return res.json(authors);
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(404).json({message: error.message});
        }    
    };
```

I'm getting this issue:

`"Book is associated to Author using an alias. You must use the 'as' keyword to specify the alias within your include statement."`

in my file authors model I have:

```
Author.hasMany(Book, { as: "books", foreignKey: "authorId"});
Book.belongsTo(Author, { as: "author", foreignKey: "authorId"});
```

so, what's wrong?? what I'm doing bad??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the alias based on your model.

**Here is an example**:

```
import { Author } from '../models/author.js'
import { Book } from '../models/book.js';

export async function getItems(req, res){ 
    try {
        const authors = await Author.findAll({
            include: [{ model: Book, as: 'books' }]
        })
        return res.json(authors);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({message: error.message});
    }    
};
```